# Construct points on a circle and find their distance

Tags: geometry, circles

AC, the diameter of a circle is of 10 cm. B and D are points lying on the circle on either side of AC. BC equals 6 and AD equals 5. Find BD!

I am getting 10 as my answer asuming that BD passes through the center. How ever i am not sure that BD passes through the centre?
My line of approach: 
Let the centre be O. SO,

BO = CO = 5 = AO = DO. 
 ANSWER BO PLUS DO = 10

i am feeling this is not correct.

Comment: I think there must be a mistake in your question. You are asking for the value of BD when it is already given!!

Comment: Sorry it was a typing mistake..Its BC which is equal to 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\measuredangle DCA=30^{\circ}$ because $AD=AO=DO$.

$\measuredangle ACB=\arccos\frac{BC}{AC}=\arccos\frac{3}{5}.$

Thus, by low of sines

$$BD=10\sin\left(30^{\circ}+\arccos\frac{3}{5}\right)=$$
$$=10\left(\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{3}{5}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}\cdot\frac{4}{5}\right)=3+4\sqrt3.$$

Comment: Typing mistake. BC equals 6

Comment: @Girish Arora I fixed my post. See now please. Thank you!

Comment: Can you upload a pic of the diagram?

Comment: @Girish Arora I don't know to draw in computer. I am sorry. I am ready to explain. Draw circle and cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ such that $AC$ is a diameter of the circle, $AO=OD=AD=5$ and $BC=6$. Now, ask your question.